# C++ working with files and directory

Tags: c++, file, csv, directory

I have school project and i need work with files. First of all i need open csv file which is in directory "vstupnidata" in root of my program directory. 
My solution which doesn't work:

```
string directory= "..\\vstupnidata\\";
string file= "ucty2015.csv";

ifstream VstupniSoubor((directory+file).c_str());

if (!(VstupniSoubor.is_open())){ //I am always here
VypisChybyV1();
return 1;
}
```

When i change it to this and dont use directory "vstupnidata", everything is OK but i need open it from directory:

```
string directory= "";
string file= "ucty2015.csv";

ifstream VstupniSoubor((directory+file).c_str());

if (!(VstupniSoubor.is_open())){
VypisChybyV1();
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Show us the directory tree between the executable and the file.

Comment: Your executable should reside in the root directory, right? Try `"vstupnidata\\"`.

Comment: LogicStuff.. Thanks.. it works...

LOL..

Comment: BTW, current directory is `"./"`, not `"../"`

Comment: Is it linux/unix directory or windows?

Comment: windows... LogicStuff helped me already